# Is it possible to make Guitar tone sound like Harmonium?

Tags: guitar

I know to play guitar and I can't play Harmonium. I like harmonium sound very much. So, if it is possible to make Harmonium sound from guitar, then we have infinite possibility to compose music. So I am thinking the possibility of making Harmonium sound from guitar. Is it possible ? if so, how can we do it ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a special pedalboard made by Boss, that will help make any sound you like using a guitar. Unfortunately, it needs an electric guitar, and a special pickup, usually fixed properly into the guitar. All at a fair cost!

You're not going to get what you want cheaply or effectively without that sort of thing - or getting a guitar to produce a MIDI signal, and then you'll need a sound processor to plug into - and an amp to be able to hear it.

Comment: There are some pedals that can make a guitar sound like an organ.  I don't know if any go for a harmonium in particular, but it wouldn't be particularly difficult for a pedal designer to achieve such an effect than to achieve many of the other effects that pedals do, in fact, achieve.

Comment: @supercat - the Boss pedal I have GR55 uses the signal from a special pup which can then produce a lot of sounds - organs included - and when MIDId through another processor, assuming *it* has a harmonium sound in its inventory, hey presto. But of course, by then, it's NOT a 'guitar tone', which is strangely what the OP asked.

Comment: There are units that process the six strings separately to produce separate MIDI channels that can then do just about anything, but there are also units that decompose the sound from the guitar into its constituent frequencies and then shape them.  The full-sized Electro-Harmonix Polyphonic Octave Generator has some settings that sound a bit like an organ (I've tried that one), but I've some videos of other pedals sound even more like one (though I forget the names).

Comment: A quick google search turns up Electro-Harmonix B9 Organ Machine and the EarthQuaker Devices Organizer.